# Continue edit sketching image using sketch.js

Tags: java, javascript, image, sketching

I am using example from sketch.js(http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) to draw sketching and able to save it in directory as an image file.

The problem is how to continue editing the sketching image after I able to render it?

Any suggestion or solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//declare an array
var canvas;

$('#buttonSave').click(function () {
   //saves all actions you made in your canvas
   canvas = $('#canvasId').sketch().actions 
});

$('#buttonRetrieve').click(function () {
    //iterates through your array, adds and redraws each action
    $.each(canvas, function (i, val) {
        $('#canvasId').sketch().actions.push(val);
        $('#canvasId').sketch().redraw();
        });
});
```